# jQuery Submit Function - How not to have it binded if already binded

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$('#xxxxx').submit(function() {
....
});
```

This is contained within a script that gets called w jQuery getScript... How can I make sure this bind only gets applied once? And or, clear out beforehand?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#xxxxx').unbind('submit').submit(function() {
....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use 'unbind' :

```
$('#xxxxx').unbind('click').
    bind('click', function() {
         ....
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the form when attaching the handler. When attaching again, just check if the class is already added to the form.

```
var $xxxx = $('#xxxx')
if (!$xxxx.hasClass('handleradded')) {
  $xxxx.submit(function(){
      ....
  }).addClass('handleradded');
}
```

Solutions given by others are good ones. I just wanted to give you an alternative. :)

Comment: You could also use `data()` there.

Comment: sure, that will also word but I am not sure whether adding/checking class names is faster or adding/checking `data`.

Comment: I'm not sure what is faster, but at least you wouldn't be overloading the class for a method it wasn't intended for.